# Redirect sed output to tr

Tags: linux, sed, xargs

How do I redirect the output of a sed command as input to a tr command?

Comment: The output of the sed command is on multiple lines.

Comment: 9 questions, and not a single answer selected...

Answer (score 5):

use pipe line "|"

sed ... | tr -d '...'

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `tr`. The `y` map predicate can do transliteration from within sed.

Comment: one difference is tr has other options as well. but yes, if its simple transliteration, the 'y' predicate of sed is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your comment, you say that the output of your `sed` command is on multiple lines.  If it truly is on multiple lines, and not a wrap around, you could use a for loop

```
for i in $(sed ".."); do tr "$i"; done
```

Comment: That's not necessary, `tr` can handle multiline input. And you're feeding the output of `sed` as *instructions* to `tr`, but with no *input*. And, in general, using for that way can be a problem because spaces are delimiters. It would be better to use a `while read` loop. Something like `sed 's/foo/bar/' file | while read -r line; do echo "$line" | tr a B ; done` would *work* but the loop is unnecessary unless you were doing some other processing inside it.